# User scope with Zend Framework

Tags: oop, zend-framework, design-patterns

I'm switching a Zend Framework application from mono-user to multi-user.

What is the best approach to include the user scope in the controllers ?

One way would be to add the user id in each methods in every controllers:

```
/application/controllers/IndexController.php
...
public function indexAction() {
    $params['user_id'] = Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity()->id;
    $listHelper->readItems($params);
}
...
```

An other one would be to create a new User model and fetch his items :

```
/application/controllers/IndexController.php
...
public function indexAction() {
    $userModel = new application_models_user();
    $userModel->find(Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity()->id);
    $userModel->readItems();
}
...
```

I'm wondering what's the best approach that would allow me to write minimal code and if you have another idea to "automagically" add the user scope (db scope, plugin...).

Comment: write a plugin that does authorization and access control start with http://www.ens.ro/2012/03/20/zend-authentication-and-authorization-tutorial-with-zend_auth-and-zend_acl/ and http://codeutopia.net/blog/2009/02/06/zend_acl-part-1-misconceptions-and-simple-acls/

Answer (score 1):

Create an abstract class by extending Zend_Controller_Action

```
abstract class My_Controller_Action extends Zend_Controller_Action  {


private $userModel;

public function getUserModel() {
 if(is_null($this->userModel)) $this->userModel  = new application_models_user();
 return $this->userModel;

}
public function getUserId() {
  return $this->getUserModel()->find(Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity()->id);
}

}
```

Now use this class as base class for your controllers.